# setInterval увеличить на 10, а не 1

Tags: setinterval

А как увеличить значение counter на 10 каждый секунд... у меня получается на 1

```js
'use strict';

setInterval(() => {

  const somEl = document.querySelector('[data-id="counter"]');
  somEl.__counterValue = somEl.textContent;

  somEl.textContent ++;


}, 1000);
```

```html
<div>Нас уже <span data-id="counter">0</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Синтаксис:

```
let timerId = setTimeout(func|code, [delay], [arg1], [arg2], ...)
```

Параметры:

- `func|code` - Функция или строка кода для выполнения. Обычно это функция. По историческим причинам можно передать и строку кода, но это не рекомендуется.
- **delay - Задержка перед запуском в миллисекундах (1000 мс = 1 с). Значение по умолчанию – 0.**

```js
'use strict';

setInterval(() => {

  const somEl = document.querySelector('[data-id="counter"]');
  //somEl.__counterValue = somEl.textContent;

  somEl.textContent = parseInt(somEl.textContent) + 10;


}, 10000);
//     ^------
```

```html
<div>Нас уже <span data-id="counter">0</span></div>
```

Comment: @mat см. ответ с исправлением

Comment: @mat ну сделай тоже самое для этой переменной. Не вижу проблем